# mysql error.log keep being empty

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, logging

I'm replacing a previous server admin on a Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS.

I have an issue with the error logs from mysql.
They are empty and they keep being empty. :(

I have edited /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
log_error               = /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

Nothing is logged anyway

```
rw-rw---- 1 mysql adm      0 2012-04-23 01:09 error.log
```

What am i missing...

Comment: Yes Marcus, i restarted on each change.
And log_error seams ok.

Comment: Dammit, this is exactly the problem I'm having. My mysql log files are empty and I'm trying to figure out how to enable logging. This is a very relevant question to me.